# How to redirect user to my Telegram game?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I created a game and it has a PLAY button. When user clicks on PLAY button it must to redirect to my game page but how? There is nothing in Telegram introductions about this.  I use AnswerCallbackQuery:

```
var redirectToGame = new AnswerCallbackQuery(update.CallbackQuery.Id) { Url = "MY_GAME_URL.html?" };
await bot.MakeRequestAsync(redirectToGame);
```

but every good working games like "MATH BATTLE" has an encrypted string in their url like this:

eyJ1IjoxMTk1NDE2MDUsIm4iOiJGYXJ6aW4gS2FuemkiLCJnIjoiTWF0aEJhdHRsZSIsImNpIjoiLTcxNzY2OTkxMzg3OTM0MzEwMzUiLCJpIjoiQkFBQUFPNGFBQUJsRHlBSGNYMG5EbEFFVFk4In00Y2MyMTUwYjdiZGQ3NjU2ZTNkZTAyNjdhYjI1MDRlMQ==

This is the data that the game needs to interact with telegram, but my redirected url has not this. my url is only this:

http://MY_GAME_URL.html?#tgShareScoreUrl=tg%3A%2F%2Fshare_game_score%3Fhash%3DvyOKf2wRilFwNHZFrWdXB7VPCVZywaxSbcvn4iZnGtA

Thanks.

Comment: What is content of your encrypted string?

Comment: Content is `user_id` and `inline_message_id`.